# long lasting authentication for Windows 8 Store App with OnlineIdAuthenticator

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have a Windows 8 App that is successfully signing a user onto Live Connect using the [OnlineIdAuthenticator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701028.aspx) object.  However, the user’s access token that is retrieved from the sign on process is expiring after about an hour.  The [Live Connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243649.aspx) documentation explains how to use a refresh token to renew a user’s access token in a server side scenario.

Is it possible to use a refresh token in Win 8 apps to keep users signed in for more than an hour?  If so, how do I get the first refresh token (I don’t see it in the returned UserIdentity or OnlineIdServiceTicket objects)?

If it is not possible to use refresh tokens, is there another way to keep a user signed into their Microsoft Account in a Windows 8 App for longer than an hour?

Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the [DataProtection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465034.aspx) for more information on storing sensitive data across sessions.